# badge count click does not shows badges user earned

Tags: support, feature-request, user-experience

The new profile view is really good. It shows more better picture of profile. I just noticed one thing I am not sure previously it was available or not  but It would be god user experience I think.

Currently on user profile we see gold,silver and bronze badge count, but when we click one of these count nothing happens.

For examle,shouldn't it show gold badges user earned if user clicks the gold badge count?

[image]

Comment: There is a [master bug/feedback post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list) on MSE.  It may be useful if you posted it there.

Comment: Should I post there??

Comment: Definitely won't hurt if you want to get more attention to your feature request

Comment: posted there thanks for referring to it